# Scraping Aliexpress Order

Tags: python, selenium

I opened a dropshipping account, and usually I go and manually place the orders on Aliexpress. I wanted to **scrape** the all the orders that I placed that got shipped, and I wanted to use Web **Scraping** with Python to do that, so that I have every order on an excel sheet. However, when the program goes to write the email and password, Aliexpress and Google know that is a python program and it does not allow me to sign in to the account so that I can scrape the orders.
I am using Selenium and Python. Google its noticing the Selenium and Python, I would like to know if there is a way to hide it. I tried everything I could. Below is the simple code that I used just to try to access the account.

````
from selenium import webdriver
import time
path='C:\chromedriver.exe'

driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get("https://aliexpress.com/orderList")



email=driver.find_element_by_name('fm-login-id')

print("found the place to type the email")
email.send_keys("email")

email=driver.find_element_by_name('fm-login-password')
email.send_keys("Password")
login=driver.find_element_by_class_name('fm-button').click()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I used undetected-chromedriver when i had to scrape aliexpress https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/.